# pcolormesh account for missing values

Tags: python, matplotlib, simulation

I'm using the following piece of code to visualise the evolution of the 2D Ising Model:

```
Plot = plt.figure()

for i, _ in enumerate(SamplePoints):
    Plot.add_subplot(PlotSpace, PlotSpace, i+1) 
    plt.tick_params(left = False, right = False, labelleft = False,
                    labelbottom = False, bottom = False)  
    plt.pcolor(State[:,:,i], cmap=plt.cm.RdBu)
    plt.title("System after %g steps" %(SamplePoints[i]))
    plt.axis('tight')
plt.suptitle("Evolution of a %d x %d lattice of spins. T = %g, H = %g"
             % (Size, Size, T, H))   
plt.tight_layout()
```

H and T are just numbers.

It takes a list, SamplePoints and a list of States from a simulation of the Ising Model, which is a 3D array, each 2D 'slice' is an array of 1's and -1's corresponding to the system at a sample point.
The problem I'm getting is this: When the system equilibrates at low temperatures, the state becomes either **all** 1's or **all** -1's. I'm guessing this is causing it to suddenly switch from displaying 1's as blue to red, because 1 suddenly goes from the highest value to the lowest (only) value, which results in weird behaviour like this:

[image: pcolormesh behaving weird]

How can I get it to colour things as if it was considering both 1's and -1's, even if it only "see's" one?

Comment: You need `plt.pcolor(..., vmin=-1, vmax=1)` to tell matplotlib which values correspond to the lowest and highest colors.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! :)
I'm not sure how I missed that in the documentation, I must've read it 10 times...